# Routing in Mvc4 with id Issue in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

**Event Controller**

```
  public class EventController : Controller {

  public ViewResult Browse(Int32 EventId) {
   return View();
    }
  }
```

**Browse-View**

```
 @model IEnumerable<Events.WebUI.Models.EventModel>
 @foreach (var e in Model) {
 <div id="event-content">
 <img src="@e.LogoUrl" width="512px" title="event header" height="83px">
 </div>
 <div class="event-text">
  @e.EventName
 @Html.ActionLink(@e.EventName, "Browse", "Event", new { EventId = @e.EventId })
 </div>
```

Here i want to use action method so that it should route to a action link with id as  localhost/Event/Browse/1 and on hover it should show the link

Please Help me to resolve this issue, i also routed the path in route.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(@e.EventName, "Browse", "Event", new { EventId = @e.EventId },null)
```

> URL will be like - localhost/Event/Browse?EventId=1

```
@Html.ActionLink(@e.EventName, "Browse", new { EventId = @e.EventId })
```

> URL will be like - localhost/Event/Browse/1

Both methods should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

**1. General settings that works for all similar cases.**

```
routes.MapRoute("Events", "{controller}/{action}/{eventId}", new {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            eventId = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
```

**2. Specific setting that works only for this case.**

```
routes.MapRoute("EventsSpecific", "Event/Browse/{eventId}",
                            new {
                                controller = "Event",
                                action = "Index",
                                eventId = UrlParameter.Optional
                            });
```

You need to apply this in `RouteCollection` in RouteConfig.cs file inside the App_Start. But I've never tried `route.config` before but I'm sure they shouldn't make a big difference.

**Last thing.**
Use **Camel Case** for parameter names such as `eventId`, instead of `EventId`. This is just a best practice.

Hope this helps.